# Script causes Unity to become unresponsive and freezes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, freeze

I made a script. The purpose of the script was deactivate the objects called "target", to randomly choose one of the targets and activate it.

I use the targets to make a NavMeshAgent go to them. When the NavMeshAgent reaches the one that has been previously activated, it is deactivated and another one is randomly activated.

The thing is that when I made the script and went to test it, in the playmode, Unity froze, and looking in the task manager I saw that it stopped responding. I had to close Unity from the task manager. When I deactivated the script in the inspector, my game was running perfectly when I tested it in playmode.

I want to add one thing before anything else. Before Unity started to freeze, I was getting this error: "LS Allocator ALLOC_TEMP_TLS, underlying allocator ALLOC_TEMP_MAIN has unfreed allocations, size 560", but I stopped getting it when Unity started freezing.

I leave the code here to see if anyone can find the problem:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class TargetManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform[] targets;

    private void Start()
    {
        // Obtener todos los targets del objeto
        targets = GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
        // Eliminar el primer elemento del array, ya que es el propio objeto y no queremos que sea considerado como un target
        targets = targets.Skip(1).ToArray();

        // Desactivar todos los targets al inicio
        foreach (Transform target in targets)
        {
            target.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }

        // Activar un target aleatorio al inicio
        ActivateRandomTarget();
    }

    public void ActivateRandomTarget()
    {
        // Desactivar todos los targets
        foreach (Transform target in targets)
        {
            target.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }

        // Obtener un índice aleatorio del array
        int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, targets.Length);
        // Activar el target aleatorio
        targets[randomIndex].gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

I can't find what part of the code might be causing this, but I think there is some loop or something, because the game only freezes when a few seconds have passed. Sorry but I don't have much programming experience.

I have tried to optimize the code, but it keeps giving me an error. I haven't found anything on the internet, I don't know if I haven't searched well or if there really isn't anything.

I tried to look at the Profiler when Unity freezes, but I couldn't tell you where the problem could be.

Here is an attempt to optimize the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class TargetManager : MonoBehaviour
{
   public List<GameObject> targets = new List<GameObject>();

    private int currentTargetIndex = -1;

    private void Start()
    {
        // Desactivar todos los targets al inicio
        foreach (GameObject target in targets)
        {
            target.SetActive(false);
        }

        // Activar un target aleatorio al inicio
        ActivateRandomTarget();
    }

    public void ActivateRandomTarget()
    {
        if (targets.Count == 0)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("No se encontraron targets. Asegúrate de agregar GameObjects al array de targets en el Inspector.");
            return;
        }

        // Desactivar el target actual
        if (currentTargetIndex >= 0 && currentTargetIndex < targets.Count)
        {
            targets[currentTargetIndex].SetActive(false);
        }

        // Obtener un índice aleatorio del array
        int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, targets.Count);
        // Activar el nuevo target aleatorio
        targets[randomIndex].SetActive(true);

        // Actualizar el índice del target actual
        currentTargetIndex = randomIndex;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The code you've shown doesn't appear the be what is causing the issue, at least not without interaction from other code. You'll have to spend some time narrowing it down. It sounds like there is something that is blocking in an Update call if it happens after a few seconds. Disable parts of your code systematically until it stop and you'll have found what triggers the issue or at least a place to dig deeper.

Comment: A freeze always means you have an endless loop somewhere .. is maybe something happening in `OnDisable`/`OnEnable` of those target objects?

Comment: @RetiredNinja I tried disabling parts of the code like you said, and disabling the last line of code in ActivateRandomTarget() my project works perfectly. I think there is a problem when activating and deactivating the targets. The line of the code:  `targets[randomIndex].gameObject.SetActive(true);`

Comment: Is `ActivateRandomTarget` called anywhere but the start function you've shown? How does the object that is activated interact with the rest of your game?

Comment: @RetiredNinja it is called in another script, but using `Debug.Log` I can tell that the funcion `ActivateRandomTarget` is only called one time.  The object is a point to which a NavMesh Agent is directed. In this way, I create a patrol method for the NavMeshAgent randomly, making it go to targets randomly.
In the other script, the `ActivateRandomTarget` function is called if no target is activated, which is activated so that the NavMeshAgent can be directed to it.